# How to check if on Route with specific parameter in Blade with Laravel 8.x?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a sidebar on my website that shows a list of groups. Each group page in this list has the same route, but a different `groupname` parameter. The route I am using looks like this:

```
Route::get('/app/group/{groupname}/overview', [OverviewController::class, 'view'])->name("group.overview");
```

When the user is looking at a specific group, I would like that group to be highlighted in bold in the sidebar. I tried doing the following in my Blade code, but that caused all pages in the sidebar to be highlighted when I visited the page of a specific group:

```
@if( Route::is( 'group.overview', $membership->group->group_name ) ) class="active" @endif
```

How do I check whether I am on a specific route, with a specific parameter?

Comment: You have the correct approach, but your `Route::is()` check seems to be returning `true` for each loop iteration, thus applying `class="active"` to all elements.

Comment: did you mean current route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to match by the parameter instead:

```
@if( request()->route('groupname') == $membership->group->group_name ) class="active" @endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:
`@if(Request::is('overview/'.$membership->group->group_name') ) class="active"`

Comment: But that's not how the route is defined... Did you mean `Request::is('/app/group/' . $membershi->group->group_name . '/overview')`?

Comment: You're absolutely right. Spaced on the first part where the route is actually defined.

Comment: No worries :) I knew what you were aiming for. Cheers!